# Invalid Number In substr

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I Used substring for this query

```
to_number(substr(skidno,instr(skidno,'/')+1,length(skidno)))
```

this i'll pass for ths query Skid no 'MMM-1718/000325 / 1' i got Invalid Number

Comment: I guess you get the blank and the 1 and this can not converted to a number

Comment: where's query exactly?

Comment: skid no pass for ths query

Comment: Your `substr()` returns `000325 / 1`. This value cannot be cast to number. Changes depend on what do You want: `325` or `1`?

Comment: i want after '/' this

Comment: after second '/'

Comment: So use `-1` as third parameter of [`instr`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_1103.htm#OLADM564) to start search from the end of the string.

Comment: After "second" slash, or after "last" slash? (What if the string has only one slash, or three slashes? If it always has **exactly** two slashes, say so in the problem statement.) Please edit **the original question** with the additional information; showing it in a Comment is not very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your need is to extract the part after the 2nd occurrence of "/"; the following query will suffice your need ---

```
select to_number(trim('/' FROM
                      substr('MMM-1718/000325 / 1',
                             instr('MMM-1718/000325 / 1', '/', 1, 2))))
  from dual;
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use `regexp_substr`. If you want to only get the number at the end of the value:

```
to_number(regexp_substr(skidno, '\d+$'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot convert it to number because you will get "/" in the result.
Result: '000325 / 1'.

If you only require only the number between '/' then try below :

```
to_number(substr(skidno ,instr(skidno  ,'/')+1,
 instr(skidno ,'/',1,2) -instr(skidno ,'/',1,1)-1 ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you need part of the string that begins after second occurrence of '/' character and goes to the end of the string, the following solution is probably the easiest using substr/instr:

```
with t as
(
  select 'MMM-1718/000325 / 1' mystring
    from dual
)
select to_number(substr(mystring, instr(mystring, '/', 1, 2) + 1))
  from t;
```

Note: in this case you just have to define starting position in substr function; length of the string is not needed.

Comment: Although this is more or less what Pratik wrote in his answer.